# Locale.forLanguageTag() vs new Locale()

Tags: java, localization, locale

Which one to use?

```
final Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US");
```

or

```
final Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
```

Both of them have tons of code when you look at their implementations and I cannot see from this code which one is faster or should be preferred.

As I use it for every single request to my web application, it would be nice to know which one is more suitable for my case.

Comment: For that very specific case using no constructor at all but instead the already existing static final `Locale.US` would be best. Are the parameters you pass into it variable and you therefor cannot use the existing defined static variable?

Comment: _On the whole_ I would say it is better to use a factory method when one is provided, because it gives the opportunity to reuse an existing instance rather than creating a new one every time it is invoked (as with `new`). This is not to say you won't get a new instance with the factory method, just that you don't have to. But, if there is a static member, as mentioned by @OHGODSPIDERS, that's even better again.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thanks for your answer. I used en-US just as an example and also am aware of this constant. But I'll be getting different values such as "hr-HR", "hr", "sr-RS" and so, which are not defined in constants.

Comment: Do I remember correctly that `forLanguageTag()` gives stricter argument validation? If so, use it, validation is invaluable.

Comment: So you basically get a single language tag as your input? In that case even without knowing the factory method uses a cache the case should be obvious: don't parse the input yourself but let the well tested `forLanguageTag()` do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

## Constants

`Locale` class provides a number of constants for frequently used locales: `Locale.CANADA`, `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`, `Locale.CHINA`, `Locale.UK`, etc.

Instead of creating a new instance of locale for *English* as a language and *US* as a country via `new Locale("en", "US")` it's preferable to use static field `Locale.US`.

## Locale constructors

There are three overloaded constructors which allow you to create a `Local` object from language, country and variant.

- [`Locale(language)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String))
- [`Locale(language, country)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))
- [`Locale(language, country, variant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String))

If you're enough with this information, go with a constructor.

**Note:** constructor call always creates a **new** object in memory.

## Locale.forLanguageTag

Static method [`Locale#forLanguageTag()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag(java.lang.String)) allows to construct an instance of `Locale` by providing [IETF BCP 47 language tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) (*also see [RFC 4647 "Matching of Language Tags"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647) and [RFC 5646 "Tags for Identifying Languages"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646)*).

Withing a *language tag* apart from the *language* and *country* you can specify various details like *calendar*, *numeric system*, *currency*.

**Note:** `forLanguageTag()` (as well as `Local.Builder`) after parsing is complete, provides an instance from the Cache (if already exists).

Example:

```
Locale buddhistCal = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-EN-u-ca-buddhist");
Locale arabicNum = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-EN-u-nu-arab");
Locale thaiNum = Locale.forLanguageTag("en-EN-u-nu-thai");
        
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.localizedBy(buddhistCal)));
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.localizedBy(arabicNum)));
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.localizedBy(thaiNum)));
```

*Output:*

```
2022-09-07
2565-09-07     // buddhist calendar
٢٠٢٢-٠٩-٠٧     // arabic numbers
๒๐๒๒-๐๙-๐๗    // thai numbers
```

Comment: This far I know already. My concern was more about performance and memory footprint than just plain usage. I am aware there is a cache for Locale instances so I guess  the same locale won't be created each time again, but rather fetched from cache.
But behind the stage there are tons of parsing and other code that I didn't analyze and it would be nice to know which one of both I mentioned does less parsing and other processing. Hope it's clear now what I wanted.

Comment: @horvoje *"the same locale won't be created each time again"* - a **new** instance would be created every time a **constructor** is being used. Conversely, with `forLanguageTag()` or `Locale.Builder` you'll get an instance from a Cache. Here's a proof regarding built-in caching of locales: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/uRG

Comment: @horvoje *"performance and memory footprint"* - so your concern is whether you can rely on the Cache for Locale objects? There are many moving in `forLanguageTag()` which being galvanized into action before an instance from the Cache can be provided. I guess you are using a limited set of Locales in your application, so you might maintain your own cache.

Comment: Are the equivalents of `-u-ca-buddhist`, `-u-nu-thai`, etc also available somehow via the `variant` parameter of the 3-parameter `Locale` constructor? It would seem so but I can't see it specifically stated or denied anywhere and my attempts to guess how have all failed.